# gradle spring boot pass environment variables to embedded vuejs app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, environment-variables

I have a `spring boot 2` app with embedded `vuejs` font-end at `/static`, using gradle `5.1`. The app is designed to be hosted on different servers, so the API url for vuejs app must be dynamic.

The most reasonable solution i can think of is to set `API_IP` environment variables at the servers and let the `vuejs` app retrieve them like this:

```
let url = `http://${process.env.API_IP}:9090/api`;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    url = `http://localhost:8090/api`;
}
```

gradle build script:

```
bootJar {
    dependsOn ':ui:jar'

    into('BOOT-INF/classes/static') {
        from "${project(':ui').projectDir}/dist"
    }

    launchScript {
        properties 'inlinedConfScript': 'startScript'
    }
}
```

However, i'm failing to pass the environment variable to vue app. Each try ends up with `process.env.API_IP` being `undefined`. `process.env` always consists only of `BASE_URL` and `NODE_ENV`.

**tried:**

1. `export API_IP=*ip*` and then run the spring boot app.
2. set the variable in `/etc/environment`, logout, login, run the spring boot app
3. pass it as run argument `-DAPI_IP=*api*`
4. set `JAVA_OPTS=-DAPI_IP=*api*`

according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html :

5. create file for `inlinedConfScript` containing `API_IP=*api*` and `JAVA_OPTS=-DAPI_IP=*api*` or only one of each.
6. create `.conf` file in the same dir with the `.jar` file withe the same value options as in `#5`.

Please help :)

Comment: The vue is build and compile into static files, so I think what you tried have no effect on these static files.(change environment variables, restart spring...)

Comment: It's static, can not change, can not read environment variables. The `proccess.env` is the env while you do `npm build`.  In your case, if your vue is served by springboot, they are on the same host, no need to specific `ip:port`, just request to '/path/url'.

Comment: However is do need to specify the port since it's not typical 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution was in removing the ip/domain from the vuejs requests as the @tianzhipeng's comment. However i can run the back-end only at port `8080` in this case.